# How to convert this code into jQuery each function?

Tags: jquery

How to convert this code into a jQuery each function? It's not good to repeat the code and I want to add more input field and I see that I will make more variables, if and else statement if I will continue with this code. I think jQuery each function will be the way to solve this problem. Sorry I'm just newbie in using jQuery.

```js
    var username = $('input[name=username]');
    var firstname = $('input[name=firstname]');
    var lastname = $('input[name=lastname]');
    var result = '';
    if(username.val() == ''){
     username.parent().addClass('has-error');
    }else{
     username.parent().removeClass('has-error');
     username.parent().addClass('has-success')
     result +='1';
    }
    if(firstname.val() == ''){
     firstname.parent().addClass('has-error');
    }else{
     firstname.parent().removeClass('has-error');
     firstname.parent().addClass('has-success')
     result +='2';
    }
    if(lastname.val() == ''){
     lastname.parent().addClass('has-error');
    }else{
     lastname.parent().removeClass('has-error');
     lastname.parent().addClass('has-success')
     result +='3';
    }
    if(result == '123'){
     $.ajax({
      type: 'ajax',
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
       if(response.success){ 
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
        if(response.type == "add"){
         var type = 'added';
        } else if(response.type == "edit"){
         var type = 'updated';
        }
        $('.alert-success').html('User '+type+' succesfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
        showAllUser();
       } else{
        alert('Error');
       }
      },
      error: function(){
       alert("Failed to add");
      }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
var hasError = true;
$(form).find("input").each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
         hasError = true;
    }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-success')
         hasError = false;
    }

});

if(!hasError){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if(response.success){ 
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                    if(response.type == "add"){
                        var type = 'added';
                    } else if(response.type == "edit"){
                        var type = 'updated';
                    }
                    $('.alert-success').html('User '+type+' succesfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                    showAllUser();
                } else{
                    alert('Error');
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Failed to add");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

After a quick refactor...

```js
var username = $('input[name=username]');
var firstname = $('input[name=firstname]');
var lastname = $('input[name=lastname]');

var valid = true;
var fields = [username, firstname, lastname];

$.each(fields, function(i, field) {
  if (field.val() == '') {
    field.parent().addClass('has-error');
    valid = false;
  } else {
    field.parent().removeClass('has-error');
    field.parent().addClass('has-success')
  }
});

if (valid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
        if (response.type == "add") {
          var type = 'added';
        } else if (response.type == "edit") {
          var type = 'updated';
        }
        $('.alert-success').html('User ' + type + ' succesfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
        showAllUser();
      } else {
        alert('Error');
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Failed to add");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var hasErrors = false;
$('input[name=username], input[name=firstname], input[name=lastname]').each(function(index, elem) {

  var $elem = $(elem);

  if($elem.val() == ''){
      $elem.parent().addClass('has-error');
      hasErrors = true;
  }else{
      $elem.parent().removeClass('has-error');
      $elem.parent().addClass('has-success');
  }

});

if(!hasErrors){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success){ 
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                if(response.type == "add"){
                    var type = 'added';
                } else if(response.type == "edit"){
                    var type = 'updated';
                }
                $('.alert-success').html('User '+type+' succesfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                showAllUser();
            } else{
                alert('Error');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed to add");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: It had a bug on the hasErrors setting and the each function parameters. It should work now. BTW, there's no call to 'toLowerCase' function, so it should not trigger that error.